# How To scroll to a div which moves off screen on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

http://jsfiddle.net/qg9hv5g7/3/

```js
$(".button").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("b");   
});
```

```css
.a {
  height: 200px;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  background: red;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.b {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  background: blue;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

When i click on 9th div it goes off screen how can i automatically scroll to the div's new location when it is clicked on

Comment: I doesn't go of screen.. It just get's a little bit larger.. Can you create a JSFiddle to simulate the problem please?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qg9hv5g7/3/ here it is @ThomasBormans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this link help? It shows the various methods of scrolling to particular elements.

http://www.robertprice.co.uk/robblog/2013/02/using-jquery-to-scroll-to-an-element/

I created a jsfiddle for reference:

http://jsfiddle.net/dboots/kg3d4Ly8/

```
function scrollToElement(el) {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: ($(el).offset().top)
    },500);
}
```

Comment: what you gave is with different id's but in my code i have same class and id http://jsfiddle.net/qg9hv5g7/3/ @Don

Comment: It accepts any html element, so even the use of `this` from your click handler. See http://jsfiddle.net/dboots/h4mnf8qj/1/ using your jsfiddle.